# OriginateAction Variables joining issue

Tags: variables, asterisk, asteriskami, asternet

I am trying to use C# AsterNET `OriginateAction` method to dial out calls with the Asterisk AMI. Calls are working fine But I am having issue on setting variables on this action. I set 2 variables as following:

```
oc.SetVariables( new Dictionary<string, string>(){ { "SIPADD", "10001"}, { "VQWAITER", "10002" }});
```

but when i try to get one of the variables "SIPADD" in dialplan. I get both vairables at once in joined form as "Local/10002|_VQWAITER=10001"

Dialplan:

```
exten => 999,1,NoOp((Caller ID IS: ${CALLERID(num)}))
 same =>      n,Answer()
 same =>      n,NoOp("Callback Agent Address: "${SIPADD})
 same =>      n,Dial(${SIPADD})
 same =>      n,Hangup()
```

Follwoing is above CLI trace of above dialplan:

[image]

Can anyone please guide me whats the issue here? I want to get these variables separately an not joined like this.

For now as a work arround i am splitting the joined string i get by doing following setps in dialplan:

```
 same =>      n,NoOp("Callback Agent Address: "${SIPADD})
 same =>      n,Set(localSIPAdd=${CUT(SIPADD,|,1)})
 same =>      n,Set(waiter=${CUT(SIPADD,|,2)})
 same =>      n,NoOp("localSIP: "${localSIPAdd})
 same =>      n,NoOp("waiter: "${waiter})
 same =>      n,Set(CALLERID(num)=waiter)
```

CLI for above change:

[image]

Comment: Seams like issue with tool/library used. Anyway, there are no programming question here, offtopic.

Comment: Missing Asterisk version number and AsterNET version number. Actually mentioning the third-party library is especially important if that is what you want help with.

Comment: Bug report on AsterNET: https://github.com/AsterNET/AsterNET/issues/220

Comment: @Deantwo Asterisk 16.6.2 and AsterNET 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using **Asterisk-Java** library. As per its documentation there are two methods available for variables. `SetVariable` and `SetVariables`. Both variables accept different types for the input parameters, i.e String and Map respectively.

I am not a Java developer, but I think updating your code like following may fix your issue.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("SIPADD","10002");
map.put("VQWAITER","10003");

oc.SetVariables(map);
```

Comment: I am using C# API AsterNET for this and yes I have tried both SetVariable and SetVariables but the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a minor bug in AsterNET v1.3.0 when using Asterisk versions newer than v13. See [AsterNET issue #220](https://github.com/AsterNET/AsterNET/issues/220) for details.

Current workaround is to manually set the [`VAR_DELIMITER`](http://asternet.github.io/AsterNET/html/F_AsterNET_Manager_ManagerConnection_VAR_DELIMITER.htm) property on the connection after connecting to the Asterisk server.

```
managerConnection.VAR_DELIMITER = new char[] { ',' };
```